# Mapping Python Dict keys to another Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Due to some poor planning I have a script that expects a python dict with certain keys however, the other script that creates this dict is using a different naming convention.

Unfortunately, due to translations that have already taken place it looks like I'll need to convert the dict keys.

Basically go from

```
 {'oldKey':'data'}
```

to

```
 {'newKey':'data'}
```

I was thinking of creating a dict:

```
 {'oldKey':'newKey'}
```

and iterate through the dict to convert from oldKey to newKey however is this the most efficient/pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Yes it is, because that's exactly what dicts are for.

Comment: Pretty much.  What's stopping you from changing the output of one script or the expected input of the other?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this which use dictionaries, but one of them might be more efficient depending on the coverage of the key usage.

a) With a dictionary comprehension:

```
old_dict = {'oldkey1': 'val1', 'oldkey2': 'val2',
            'oldkey3': 'val3', 'oldkey4': 'val4',
            'oldkey5': 'val5'}

key_map = {'oldkey1': 'newkey1', 'oldkey2': 'newkey2',
           'oldkey3': 'newkey3', 'oldkey4': 'newkey4',
           'oldkey5': 'newkey5'}

new_dict = {newkey: old_dict[oldkey] for (oldkey, newkey) in key_map.iteritems()}

print new_dict['newkey1']
```

b) With a simple class that does the mapping. (Note that I have switched the order of key/value in `key_map` in this example.) This might be more efficient because it will use lazy evaluation - no need to iterate through all the keys - which may save time if not all the keys are used.

```
class DictMap(object):

    def __init__(self, key_map, old_dict):
        self.key_map = key_map
        self.old_dict = old_dict

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.old_dict[self.key_map[key]]

key_map = {'newkey1': 'oldkey1',
           'newkey2': 'oldkey2',
           'newkey3': 'oldkey3',
           'newkey4': 'oldkey4',
           'newkey5': 'oldkey5'}

new_dict2 = DictMap(key_map, old_dict)

print new_dict2['newkey1']
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I was playing around with the first example but I kept getting key errors. The issue is there are around 20 different dicts each have a subset of the bigger set of keys. I am looking to have just one map from oldkey -> newkey to avoid duplication. So basically go through the old dict and convert to the new dict. Is this very inefficient?

Comment: @user7692855 I think it would be more inefficient in memory usage to iterate over all the old dict, especially if not all the keys will be accessed. But that might not matter if the dictionaries are not huge, and a simple clear process may be preferable for readability. Just to clarify - are you mapping from 20 different old dicts to one new dict, or vice versa?

Comment: Basically, the code I wrote is used to trigger an email (through a third party). The input email (also provided by a third party) has tags in one format, which then need to be translated to the other format. I know I could do 20 different dicts mapping one for each email. but as there are common variables amongst the emails I was hoping to have one translation dict.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
new_dict={key_map[oldkey]: vals for (oldkey, vals) in old_dict.items()}
```